# How to change Image from UIImageView in Loop Execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` showed for user, and in background i have a loop for download images.

How can I show the images one by one in this `UIImageView`? Since manually by setting does not work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [checkRow count]; i++) {
    NSString *url = [checkRow objectAtIndex:i];
    NSData *imageDataReceived = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [downloadImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageDataReceived]];
}
```

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear. Are you downloading these images from the Internet? Do you want to show one image while the next one is being downloaded? 1) Never do network access on the main thread. 2) It's a really bad idea to use `dataWithContentsOfURL:`. There's no error checking, no timeout, no checking to see if there is even a connection, etc.